# Validating <select> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 `<select>` elements for Day, Month and Year. And I am trying to get them validated with jQuery.

```
<li class="pseudo_day">
    <select class="mod_day" name="day">
        <option disabled selected>Day</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Like so:

```
$("select[name=day], select[name=month], select[name=year]").on('change', function(){

    var select_day = $("select[name=day]").val();
    var select_month = $("select[name=month]").val();
    var select_year = $("select[name=year]").val();

        if ( select_day.length !== 0 ) { console.log("Valid - " + select_day); }
        else { console.log("Not valid!"); }
});
```

This is the **error** I get when I run the jQuery code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (new_user.html:242)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not just use a datepicker plugin? It has the benefits of avoiding this problem completely, plus it looks a lot better.

Comment: Yes, don't reinvent the wheel. I once used [this](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/) and was quite happy with it.

Comment: I've tried it. But it didn't for me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no option is selected `select[name=day]` then `$("select[name=day]").val()` is `null` and you get the error, as we cannot read property 'length' of null. We can resolve it in many ways, but one way you can do it like:

```
var select_day = $("select[name=day]").val() || '';
var select_month = $("select[name=month]").val() || '';
var select_year = $("select[name=year]").val() || '';
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on every `change` event for your selects you are trying to get all the values. And if, for example, you changed only `year` then `month` and `day` are undefined. And then you are trying to manipulate day - `select_day.length` - by taking its length. You can use what palash suggested or check existence and type like

```
if (select_day && typeof select_day === 'string' ) ...
```

This is true only if `select_day` is a not empty string.